# NSArrayController : removeAllObjects does not refresh TableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarraycontroller

In my application I add objects directly to an ArrayController. When I want to clean all items I do:

```
[[downloadItemsController content] removeAllObjects];
```

This command however does not refresh the TableView the arraycontroller is bound to. If I remove all items and add another new items I only see that item. That is fine but if I don't add anything I still have all my items in the table.

If I do

```
[downloadItemsController prepareContent];
```

all old items are removed from the tableview but than I will get an new and empty item I can edit. I don't want that and because one of my columns has a checkboxcell I always get an row with a checkbox.

I just need an empty table with no items after I remove all existing items.

Answer (score 32):

To quickly remove all the objects from an `NSArrayController` object:

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [[anArrayController arrangedObjects] count]);
[anArrayController removeObjectsAtArrangedObjectIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range]];
```

The bindings should update automatically. See [original SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/646939/70984).

Answer (score 3):

This is because you're modifying the controller's content "behind its back." Try using the array controller's [-removeObjects:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSArrayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002042-BAJBEFJH) method.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
[anArrayController setContent:nil]
```

You can start populating its contents right away like this

```
[anArrayController addObject: @{ .... }]
[anArrayController addObject: @{ .... }.mutablecopy]
[anArrayController addObject: aDictionary]
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `removeObject..` group of methods is particularly inconvenient for a collection of Core Data objects. It seems that `remove...` is meant for those cases when we really need to get rid of the data (like when user press *'Remove'* button at UI), so the `NSArrayController` will try it's best to remove objects from Core Data DB too.

I have simple manual control of `NSArrayController` and I found that `setContent:` method works great for adding, removing and replacing the array of objects inside it. And just to clear the contents `setContents:@[]` can be used.

Comment: But unlike @rraallvv's answer, you can't start populating its contents right away. You'll get an error saying **Unrecognized selector sent to instance ...**

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you remove is the key; here I defer using a volatile bool (undoInProgress) in a revert action, using solution above to flush a change array which observing method ignores while undo is in progress:

```
volatile bool undoInProgress = 0;
- (IBAction)revert:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults * prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray * undo = [NSArray arrayWithArray:changes];
    undoInProgress = YES;

    //  We have a single key/value pair but do so in reverse order
    for (NSInteger i=[undo count]-1; i>=0; --i)
    {
        NSDictionary * change = [undo objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString * key = [change objectForKey:@"keyPath"];
        id val = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];

        [prefs setValue:val forKey:key];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [[changeController arrangedObjects] count]);
        [changeController removeObjectsAtArrangedObjectIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range]];
        undoInProgress = NO;
    });
}
```