# How to clear a NSTableView's data source

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I am trying to make a method in which the data source for my NATableView is cleared, but I cannot figure out how to do this anywhere.

Here is the code I am using to send an array called final to my table view.

```
// I want to clear it here before filling it again.  
for (int i = 0; i < [final count]; i++) {
    [myArrayController addObject: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:final[i], @"File Name", nil]];
}
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Clear like remove all the objects from the array controller?

Comment: Yup exactly, just looking for the command, I think I have the syntax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSArrayController : removeAllObjects does not refresh TableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391655/nsarraycontroller-removeallobjects-does-not-refresh-tableview)

Comment: Got the answer from the link above.


    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [[myArrayController arrangedObjects] count]);
    [myArrayController removeObjectsAtArrangedObjectIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range]];


Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an `NSMutableArray` and `myArrayController` is your mutable array you want to call

```
[myArrayController removeAllObjects];
```

before you enter the `for-loop`.